# How can i save a file i download using fetch with fs

Tags: node.js, download, stream, fs

I try downloading files with the fetch() function from github.
Then i try to save the fetched file Stream as a file with the fs-module.
When doing it, i get this error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "transform.writable" property must be an instance of WritableStream. Received an instance of WriteStream

My problem is, that i don't know the difference between WriteStream and WritableStream or how to convert them.

This is the code i run:

```
async function downloadFile(link, filename = "download") {
    var response = await fetch(link);
    var body = await response.body;
    var filepath = "./" + filename;
    var download_write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
    console.log(download_write_stream.writable);
    await body.pipeTo(download_write_stream);
}
```

Node.js: v18.7.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question. **Web streams are something new**, and they are different way of handling streams. [WritableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/webstreams.html#class-writablestream) tells us that we can create **WritableStreams** as follows:

```js
import {
  WritableStream
} from 'node:stream/web';

const stream = new WritableStream({
  write(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
  }
});
```

Then, you could create a custom stream that **writes each chunk** to disk. An easy way could be:

```js
const download_write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('./the_path');


const stream = new WritableStream({
  write(chunk) {
    download_write_stream.write(chunk);
  },
});

async function downloadFile(link, filename = 'download') {
  const response = await fetch(link);
  const body = await response.body;
  await body.pipeTo(stream);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why you can't `body.pipeTo(process.stdout)`? Your example of creating a WritableStream and calling `process.stdout.write` inside works, but why is it necessary?  In other places `stdin.pipe(stdout)` works -- what's different about `readable.pipeTo()`?

Comment: when you wait for response.body, dont it gathers all the filecontents into memory?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Readable.fromWeb`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options) to convert `body`, which is a `ReadableStream` from the [web streams API](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/), into a NodeJS `Readable` stream that can be used with the `fs` methods.

Note that [`readable.pipe`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepipedestination-options) returns another stream instantly. To wait for it to finish, you can use the promise version of [`stream.finished`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamfinishedstream-options-callback) to convert it into a `Promise`, or else you could add listeners for the `'finish'` and `'error'` events to detect success or failure.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { finished } = require('stream/promises');

async function downloadFile(link, filepath = './download') {
    const response = await fetch(link);
    const body = Readable.fromWeb(response.body);
    const download_write_stream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
    await finished(body.pipe(download_write_stream));
}
```